I wanted to swap Solana for a meme coin and now the transaction is Pending for 10 days using my Onekey wallet App
I wanted to swap Solana for a meme coin and now the transaction is Pending for 10 days using my Onekey wallet App. I tried to reboot my laptop and have updated my Onekey app and still the transaction remains in a pending status. What can I do about this as it's been this way for over 10 days now.
